# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: lob is no longer valid Error in Spring Junit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I am getting an exception while running HSQLDB script through Spring Junit.

I am using below definitions and skills to run Junit.
HSQLDB script:Schema definition

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE MIGRATION."MIG_STATUS"("STATUS_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"STATUS_DESC" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "PK_MIG_STATUS" PRIMARY KEY("STATUS_ID"))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE MIGRATION."MIG_GROUP"("GROUP_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"GROUP_ATTEMPT_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"GROUP_NAME" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC,"EMAIL_IDS" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC,"FILE_CONTENT" BLOB(1G),"SCHEDULED_BY" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC,"SCHEDULED_AT" TIMESTAMP,"START_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP,"END_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP,"STATUS_ID" INTEGER,"MIGRATION_TYPE" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC NOT NULL,"PRE_CHECK_RUN_AT" TIMESTAMP,"PRE_CHECK_STATUS" INTEGER,CONSTRAINT "PK_MIG_GROUP" PRIMARY KEY("GROUP_ID","GROUP_ATTEMPT_ID"),CONSTRAINT "FK_GROUP_STATUS" FOREIGN KEY("STATUS_ID") REFERENCES MIGRATION."MIG_STATUS"("STATUS_ID"))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE MIGRATION."MIG_COMPANY"("COMPANY_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"ATTEMPT_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"GROUP_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"GROUP_ATTEMPT_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,"COMPANY_NAME" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC,"USER_COUNT" INTEGER,"STATUS_ID" INTEGER,"START_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP,"END_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP,"MIGRATION_TYPE" VARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "PK_MIG_COMPANY" PRIMARY KEY("COMPANY_ID","ATTEMPT_ID"),CONSTRAINT "FK_COMPANY_MIG_GROUP" FOREIGN KEY("GROUP_ID","GROUP_ATTEMPT_ID") REFERENCES MIGRATION."MIG_GROUP"("GROUP_ID","GROUP_ATTEMPT_ID"),CONSTRAINT "FK_COMPANY_STATUS" FOREIGN KEY("STATUS_ID") REFERENCES MIGRATION."MIG_STATUS"("STATUS_ID"))
INSERT INTO MIG_STATUS VALUES(1,'Scheduled')
INSERT INTO "MIG_GROUP" VALUES(310,1,'mig_2274_mar4_v8',NULL,30,NULL,'2015-03-04 13:40:00.000000','2015-03-04 13:40:54.000000','2015-03-04 13:47:51.000000',201,'Forward',NULL,0)
INSERT INTO "MIG_COMPANY" VALUES(2274,5,310,1,'test31',0,400,'2015-03-04 13:40:53.000000','2015-03-04 13:47:51.000000','Forward')
```

Hibernate Entity:
    ....

```
Class 1:
@Table(name = "MIG_COMPANY")
public class Company extends BaseObject implements Cloneable {
.....

    @Expose
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Status status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID"), @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ATTEMPT_ID") })
    private Group group;
......


}
```

Class 2:

```
@Table(name = "MIG_GROUP")
public class Group extends BaseObject {

.....
    @Column(name = "FILE_CONTENT")
    private byte[] fileContent;
.....
}
```

Class 3:

```
@Repository
public class CompanyDaoHibernate<E> implements CompanyDao<E> {
    @Override
    public Company getCompanyById(final int companyId, final int attemptId) {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final Criteria criteria =
                session.createCriteria(Company.class).add(Restrictions.eq("companyId", companyId))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("attemptId", attemptId));
        return (Company) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

Class 4: Junit call

```
.....
    {
        companyManager.getCompanyById(2274, 5);
    ......
    }
```

ERROR

```
SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(146) | An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: lob is no longer valid Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.135 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

Can some one help where I am doing mistake?